# Google CloudML: Job fails after "Finished tearing down training program" even though the training hasn't completed

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to train a model using Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

I chose the `standard-1` scale tier (using the basic tier give memory exceptions which I think is due to the size(2.6GB) of the data) but my job fails after a log of "**Finished tearing down training program**" even though it is still downloading the data into the VM from the cloud storage.

It doesn't provide any Tracebacks as to what the error might be.

I have my data stored in the Cloud Storage and to make it available I use `os.system('gsutil -m cp -r location_of_data_in_cloud_storage os.getcwd()')` to store the data in the VM assigned so that it can be directly accessed by the program. This data is then loaded into the model.fit_generator() method through a generator.

[image: Job-Log1]

[image: Job-Log2]

As can be seen the data of 2.6GB hasn't been downloaded completely but the job fails before that!

Comment: Kindly point out if more details are needed, I'm new to using GCP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone else who stumbles upon this question in the future (possibly me ;) ), the problem above was occurring because the machine couldn't handle the compute and so I had to scale up a machine using the `standard_p100` scale-tier from the `basic` scale-tier in GCP which solved the problem!